# Why does android:state_selected="false" apply selector style?

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with a `listSelector` attribute. I also have defined a custom selector. Both are below.

`ListView`:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/lvequipments"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:listSelector="@drawable/wash_count_list_selector"
  android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

`selector`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="false">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/white" />
            <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I am trying to apply this `selector` style after user clicks on an item in the `ListView`. I have tried every combination of item states, but the only one that will apply the `selector` style after a user clicks the `ListView` item is `android:state_selected="false"`. I would think `android:state_selected="true"` would be applying the style? Why is this behaving as it is, or am I misunderstanding how this should work?

Answer (score 0):

check that -> [Color State List](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

PS: this should be a comment but i cant comment